# Issues with codepipeline and amazon beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been using aws elastic beanstalk for about 5 years now. It's been great. I also use it in combination with codepipeline.

Somewhere along the lines, in order to get it to deploy you had to bump the version. And sometimes delete the package-lock.

However, suddenly today it's basically brown stuff hit the fan. I can't update environments, I can't clone environments. It's just all stuck on unknown or degraded

Anybody else have these issues before?